# Missing page header in bibliography

Tags: latex, bibtex

I need help with page headers in latex. I'm using **fancyhdr** to define page header. That works on all pages except first page of bibliography(references). Since there are three pages of references, only first is missing the header, the other two are ok. I'm generating references like so:

```
%\clearpage
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatura in viri}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{library}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
```

I have tried all possible permutations of lines that are commented out to no avail.

*library* is bib file auto generated by Mendeley.

If I use

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
   \thispagestyle{fancy}
     \bibitem{Blum}  somethingorother
\end{thebibliography}
```

the problem dissapears, but I don't want to add 30+ references manually.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem has been solved like so:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatura in viri}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{library}
```

For some reason, Latex uses special pagestyles for some commands, for example bibliography uses pagestyle{plain}, and function 
\fancypagestlye{arg1}{arg2} lets you modify style *arg1* with *arg2*.
I dunno if that made any sense but more info can be found at [this](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) link under chapter *7. Redefining plain style*

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Tawcharowsky worked for me. Offroad gave a similar answer on
https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22727
which helped me. I added some comments to the proposed code snippets:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} % I used apalike instead
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography} % "Bibliography" will be the title
\bibliography{library} % "library.bib" is your bib file
```